# Limit for Visualforce pages in Salesforce Developer edition?

Tags: visualforce, force.com, limits

How many Visualforce pages i can create in salesforce? I have gone through this link
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developer_Edition
but they haven't mentioned about limit for visualforce pages. 
I can see the limit for apex code in setup->develop->Apex Classes which is of 3,000,000 characters.

Comment: I don't think there is a limit on the amount of VF pages but you would probably hit other limits first. Example: you can only deploy a maximum of 5,000 classes and triggers in one go so if all your VF pages had controllers you would hit that limit when deploying. 

You also have a limit of 3MB for all code in the org

Comment: but it is showing 5.0 MB of data storage and 20 MB file storage, I thought data storage is for code. :)

Comment: No thats object data. e.g. All the Contact and Account records. Its 5MB in a dev org and a minimum of 1GB in production

Comment: @BarCotter I'm not aware of any limit on the number of VF pages either. I'd recommend you create an answer out of your comments btw, i think they add a lot of clarity to the original question.

Comment: Ive added an answer based on my first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a limit on the amount of VF pages but you would probably hit other limits first. Ive listed out some limits below that you might run into. See [here](http://login.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) for a full list of limits

If all your VF pages had controllers you might hit this limit when deploying:

> Maximum number of class and trigger code units in a deployment of Apex
>   - 5,000

The 3 MB of apex code limit would also be used up if all your VF pages had controllers:

> Maximum amount of code used by all Apex code in an organization - 3 MB